# Trying to cross compile C++11 code in Carlston-Minot ARM Linux G++ compiler on OS X gives me an error

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, g++, cross-compiling

```
FelixMacBookPro:Debug Felix$ /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -L"/Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus" -L"/Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/librairie/lib" -I"/Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/librairie/include" -I"/Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include" -Xlinker --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs --sysroot="/Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/toolchain/sysroot" /Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/geniUSArmus/main.cpp -std=c++11 -o "Armus.exe"
In file included from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/basic_string.h:2815,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/string:52,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/array:38,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/map:61,
                 from /Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/librairie/include/i2c_api.h:11,
                 from /Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/librairie/include/libarmus.h:59,
                 from /Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/geniUSArmus/main.cpp:8:
/usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/cstdlib:126:11: error: '::at_quick_exit' has not been declared
   using ::at_quick_exit;
           ^
/usr/local/carlson-minot/crosscompilers/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/cstdlib:149:11: error: '::quick_exit' has not been declared
   using ::quick_exit;
           ^
FelixMacBookPro:Debug Felix$
```

So, from what I've read, quick_exit and at_quick_exit are C++11 features. Problem is that my code uses a lot of C++11 stuff.

The string_conversions.h file is including cstdlib

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks!

EDIT: I ran it with the -H argument, as suggested, and [here are the results](http://pastebin.com/4WZLXvgf): pastebin.com/4WZLXvgf

EDIT2:  I removed my --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs argument and it helped. I can now build my code as long as I don't use anything that comes from , which is a necessary library for what I want to do.

Comment: You're referencing them at the global namespace, are you including `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I'm not including it in my main.cpp, but I just did and it did not help. It's already being included by string_conversions.h anyway, as we can see from the long list of files

Comment: Might want to double check the header file to see if it's declared and if it is see if there's something preventing it from being compiled in. If it's not it might not be supported on that target yet. Also might want to update your post with all your findings.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the error is *in the system header*.

Comment: Run g++ with `-H` argument. Watch for standard header names in suspicious directories (like your "toolchain" directory).

Comment: @n.m. I just checked and it is indeed included at line 41 in string_conversions.h.

So, I just ran it with the -H argument and here's the output: http://pastebin.com/4WZLXvgf

It does appear 67 times.
"............ /Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h"
That can't be good, I guess? That's a standard header..

hahahahaha "suspicious toolchain directory"
I'm actually trying to use OS X and Xcode (or whatever) instead of Windows with Eclipse so I was trying to move the build arguments from there to G++ in OS X.

Comment: @n.m. I removed the inclusion of the toolchain folder as a whole from my arguments and deleted the "include" folder from it and now my error is different:
"/Users/Felix/Documents/geniUSArmus/librairie/include/lcd_bitmap.h:11:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^"

That's a standard C++ header. How come it isn't finding it ? I'll double check all the folders I'm including and linking.

Comment: @n.m. I removed my --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs argument and it helped. I can now build my code as long as I don't use anything that comes from <libarmus.h>, which is a necessary library for what I want to do. I'll keep trying stuff and I'll update this post.